# Semi-global Rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm going for?

- I have a partial in the `/views/shared/` folder that has all the fields that are in a form being used to send an email.
- A helper method with default options to render said partial (`render partial: 'shared/email_fields' locals: locals` where `locals` is a hash of default variables).
- A helper method for every form sending an email that calls the above helper method and passes in either a `FormBuilder` object or a string containing the beginning of the `name` html attribute.

The problem I'm having: Most of the email forms differ slightly which results in me having to add additional options to the `locals` hash and I feel like the global partial is becoming bloated. Is there some way of using a global partial in this way such that the partial doesn't become super bloated?

I've thought of having each form completely separate but that's bad for upkeep and DRY. I've thought of passing in the name of a partial to be rendered inside the global partial but some of these forms need the same options and are rendered from different controllers and I wouldn't want to put a bunch of partials that aren't global in the `/views/shared/` folder. Right now, I'm just sticking with the bloated global partial.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it. This is going to sound weird, but bear with me.

So, I have basically two forms in my applications. For a form that submits via javascript, it looks like this:

```
#views/shared/_remote_form.html.haml

= form_tag @presenter.form_path, 
    remote: true, 
    id: @presenter.form_id, 
    class: @presenter.form_classes, 
    data: @presenter.form_data, 
    method: @presenter.form_method do 
    .well
      = @presenter.form_inner
      .form-controls-container
        .form-controls-wrapper
          = @presenter.form_controls
```

As you can see, I use presenters. The presenters are instantiated in the relevant controller as a controller variable, so that the presenter is available to the partial. Something like:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @presenter = NewFooFormPresenter.new(self)
    render partial: 'shared/remote_form'
  end

  ...

end
```

You can see that I'm passing in the controller so that the presenter is able to render various parts of the form.

All `FormPresenters` inherit from `FormPresenterBase` that has stubbed methods for each of the methods called in the form. Something like this:

```
class FormPresenterBase

  def initialize(controller)
    @controller = controller
  end

  def form_path
    root_path
  end

  def form_id
    'bogus-form-id'
  end

  def form_classes
    'something-bogus'
  end

  def form_inner; end

  def form_controls; end

  ...

end
```

That let's me bootstrap the form without throwing a bunch of errors all the time. Naturally, that stubbed form won't really work, but that's okay because each FormPresenter will override the stubbed methods with real values. So, something like:

```
class NewFooFormPresenter < FormPresenterBase

  def form_path
    new_for_form_path
  end

  def form_id
   'new-foo-form'
  end 

  def form_classes
    'something-not-bogus'
  end

  # The form fields could be unique to this form. Or, I might have a set of common 
  # fields that I use across multiple forms. I just decide which partial has the 
  # correct set of fields and render it here.
  def form_inner
    render partial: 'new_inner_fields'
  end

  # The controls are also rendered from partials. Here, I want to have an okay 
  # button and a cancel button. So, I just call the correct partial that 
  # renders those. I call html_safe on the resultant string so that it renders 
  # correctly.
  def form_controls
    [:okay, :cancel].each_with_object("") do |control_sym, to_return|
      render partial: "shared/form_widgets/#{control_sym.to_s}_button"
    end.html_safe

  end

  ...

end
```

Of course, I can get tricky with my FormPresenters. If there are families that share common methods, I can either use further inheritance or module inclusion to keep everything DRY.

So, once I have all my basic form widgets (field combinations, controls, etc.) configured as partials, I can just mix and match in my presenter to my heart's delight. And (at least for forms), I basically never have to write another partial for the rest of my life. Whenever I need a new variant, I just spin up a new FormPresenter and customize it to give me the form I desire.

Actually, there's a little bit more to it than all of that, but hopefully this gives you a sense of another way to skin the cat.

Comment: Is that a Rails 5 thing? (We're only on 4.2.5) I've never heard of form presenters or presenters before.

Comment: No, `presenters` are a pattern. They're just plain old ruby objects. Ryan Bates has a pretty good introductory Rails Cast on the topic. Recently, I've spun up a whole new custom PORO class called `Widget` that let's me further componentize my applications. But, that's a whole other crazy story.

Comment: This seemed very strange at first but after watching the Rails Cast, this is how I'm going about this. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to have a separate partial for each form.  Take all of the items the forms have in common and put them in a partial.  You can then reference the "common items" partial within your individual form partials.  Depending on how your forms are structured, you may have several "common items" partials, but that is okay.  The goal is to keep the code organized and DRY.